# index "/" route not working when using with a prefix in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following route declaration:

```php
Route::name('test.')
    ->prefix('test')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', function() {
            dd('test');
        })->name('index');
    });
```

Trying to access `/test` will result in NotFoundException, although when calling `route('test.index')` it will resolve to `/test`.

Same exception when trying to access `/test/` and when trying to change the line:

```php
Route::get('/', function()...
```

to

```php
Route::get('', function()...
```

As soon as I modify it to

```php
Route::get('/test', function()...
```

it works when trying to access ´/test/test´ and it also resolved the uri correctly when calling `route('test.index')`.

What am I missing to to get the route working using `'/'` ?

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and paste the output of this route you defined. You will probably find a solution there.

Comment: I usually find it better to edit the RouteServiceProvider and add a whole new section to it to move routes to their own files. This way it will make your routes easier to find as well. Perhaps give that a try?

Comment: With '/' the route does not register at all. I have them extracted in their own file. The weird part is that the uri resolves fine.

Comment: Are you placing the files in: `routes.php`, `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: And please add the output of `php artisan route:list` to your question as stated by @zlatan

Comment: You probably have another route which matches `test/`. Make sure this route group is registered before the other.